# Delete elements from a dynamically updated data table

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, jboss, richfaces

I have a Richfaces **1.2** dataTable that is updated every 2 seconds using a a4j:poll request. It sends a request to the server and reRender the table adding new elements and changing the state of existing elements.

On top of that, I want to be able to delete rows from this table using a button, but the problem is that it’s possible to send a delete request (button) AND an update request (poll) at the same time, causing a concurrent call exception.

Any ideias on how to keep the table dynamically updated and be able to send delete requests at the same time? What I was trying to do is blocking the poll request when a delete button is clicked, make the delete request, and then get back at sending requests to update the table.

Queue of requests maybe?

Here's a simplified snippet of the code:

```html
    <a:form id="orders">
            
            <a:poll id="pollUpdateOrders" 
                interval="2000"
                reRender="outputPanelOrders, pollUpdateOrders"
                action="#{bean.getOrders()}" />
            
            <a:outputPanel id="outputPanelOrders">
                
                <r:dataTable id="tabelOrders" 
                    title="Orders" var="orders"
                    value="#{bean.getOrders()}" >
                    
                        <r:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Code" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{order.code}" />
                        </r:column>
                
                        <r:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Description" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{order.description}" />
                        </r:column>

                        <r:column>
                            <a:commandLink id="deleteOrder"
                                action="#{bean.deletOrder(order)}" />
                        </r:column>
                </r:dataTable>
            </a:outputPanel>
    </a:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean RichFaces 3 with JSF 1.2; you should be able to chain the operations like this (using `a4j:jsFunction`):

- onclick - disable poll
- oncomplete - remove the row
- oncomplete - enable poll